# How to make Enemy FLIP and ATTACK in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial for creating an enemy in Unity, but they didn't teach how to **flip the enemy** in case the Player goes to the other side of the map, oppose to where the enemy is.

So I tried to increase the **raycast area**, so when the Player collides with it from behind, the enemy will know that it has to flip. But something isn't working, cause it goes fine to the Player when it's facing the left side of the map, but once it flips, it totally stops working, and I can't figure it out why.

Anyone have any idea what should I do?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Skeleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Public Variables
    public Transform rayCast;
    public LayerMask raycastMask;
    public GameObject target;
    public float rayCastLength;
    public float attackDistance; //Mininum distance to attack
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float timer; // Cooldown b/w attacks
    public bool inRange; //check if the player is near
    #endregion

    #region Private Variables
    private RaycastHit2D hit;
    private Animator anim;
    private float distance; //Distance b/w enemy and player
    public bool attackMode;
    private float intTimer;
    #endregion

    void Awake() {
        intTimer = timer;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    
    void Update() {
        if (inRange)
        {
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayCast.position, Vector2.left, rayCastLength, raycastMask);
        }


        //When the player is detected
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            EnemyLogic();
        }
        // If it's not inside the raycast
        else if(hit.collider == null)
        {
            inRange = false;
        }

        // If the player leaves the range
        if (inRange == false)
        {
            anim.SetBool("canWalk", false);
            StopAttack();
            anim.SetInteger("Idle", 0);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            target = col.gameObject;
            inRange = true;
            Flip();
        }
    }

    void EnemyLogic()
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);

        if(distance > attackDistance)
        {
            Move();
            StopAttack();   
        }
        else if(attackDistance >= distance)
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        anim.SetInteger("Idle", 1);
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", true);
        if (!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("attack"))
        {
            Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(target.transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        timer = intTimer; //reset timer
        attackMode = true;

        anim.SetInteger("Idle", 1);
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
    }

    void StopAttack()
    {
        attackMode = false;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }

    // Detects if the player is on the other side
    void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        if(target.transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
        {
            rotation.y = 180f;
        }
        else
        {
            rotation.y = 0f;
        }

        transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, `unityscript` is no longer available.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this, so I don't really know what that means :/

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the enemy using localScale.  Do this:

```
        if (Player.transform.position.x < this.transform.position.x)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }else
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
```

This detects whenever the player's x position is greater or lower than the enemy and flips the whole object.